# Gulp: Error in plugin 'run-sequence(default) MSBuild failed with code 3221225477!. Gulp task Visual Studio 2017

Tags: gulp, sitecore, task-runner-explorer

While running gulp publish of Sitecore helix based solution getting below error

Error in plugin 'run-sequence(default)'
Message:
MSBuild failed with code 3221225477!
Stack:
Error: MSBuild failed with code 3221225477!
at ChildProcess. (C:\Repository\node_modules\gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-runner.js:66:25)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)

Any help?
MSBuild is getting success in Command prompt.
**Note**: I checked other solutions which was running correctly previously is even not working now.  any issue due to windows update?

Answer (score 0):

the gulp.js file given used by the Habitat Demo is also using gulp-msbuild as for using msbuild.

From this node module, you can see that it retrieves the msbuild version you have locally installed. My guesses are :

1 - gulp-msbuild is using the wrong MsBuild version (if you have multiple vs installation, might be worth it to console.log within the *node_modules\gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-finder.js*

2a - You want to make sure you have the webtools installed (you can open visual studio installer and check if you have *Web Development build tools* checked.)

2b - You also want to make sure you have this directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\
```

and these files within : `Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.dll, Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`

3 - Habitat use gulp 3.9. So you want to use a node.js versions < 12 I think, maybe <10. Personnaly would recommend trying nodejs8.17.0 as I know this one is stable with gulp 3.9

Comment: Hi Jean, the MsBuild path retuned is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" using console.log of your first comment.

Comment: I don't find 'Web Development build tools' in VS2017 installer. the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" contains only Code analysis and Python installer folder

Comment: Hi, can you download and install the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 :: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15. I am pretty sure you are missing a component on your installation that will let you get past this issue.

Comment: @shahul, were you able to resolve the issue ?

Comment: issue got resolved by changing the compatablity of MSBuild to Windows vista even I am running from windows 10

Comment: @shahul where did you make that change? if you remember

Comment: @Imad sorry for the late response. i have changed C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe